# Laravel edit records dynamic way

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

**Controllers/HomeController.php**

```
    public function edit(Task $task)
    {       
        return view('edit', compact('task'));
    }   

     public function update(Request $request, Task $task)
    {
        $request->validate(['title' => 'required|min:3', 'description' => 'required', ]);
        $task->title = $request->title;
        $task->description = $request->description;
        $task->save();
        $request->session()
            ->flash('message', 'Successfully modified the task!');
        return redirect('viewalltask');
    }
```

**routes/web.php**

```
Route::post('/{task}/', 'HomeController@update')->name('update');
```

**views/edit.blade.php**

```
 <form action="{{url('', [$task->id])}}" method="POST">
                 <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT">
                  {{ csrf_field() }}
                  <div class="row">
                     <div class="col-md-3" >
                        <label for="title" >title</label>
                        <input id="title" type="text" class="form-control" name="title" value="{{$task->title}}" required autofocus>
                     </div>
                     <div class="col-md-3">
                        <label for="description" >description</label>
                        <input id="description" type="text" class="form-control" name="description" value="{{$task->description}}" required>
                     </div>
                  </div>
                  <br>
                  <div class="row">
                     <div class="col-md-12">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" >
                        Edit
                        </button>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </form>
```

> Error :
>   Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ MethodNotAllowedHttpException
>   No message

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your routes file the you have declared the wrong method . it should be like this.

```
Route::put('/{task}', 'HomeController@update')->name('update');
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using wrong method type in routes as compare to method type in form,

```
Route::post('/{task}/', 'HomeController@update')->name('update');
```

Should work.

Comment: **Added in web.php**

`Route::post('/{task}/', 'HomeController@update')->name('update');`

**Still same error**